# Make particle system using settings on every faces of a mesh

Tags: particles, hair

Im working on a grass project and wondering if there is an option to apply hair system on every faces of a mesh. Do Blender 2.79 have something to do it so i dont need to make multiple hair systems for differents meshes?

When i say "multiple hair system for different meshes", i have multiple meshes that have faces the same size, but those meshes are not the same size. So the smaller one will have more hair per faces. I just want all meshes having the same amount of hairs. Can you guys help me with it?

Very appreciate!

[Edit]

At this moment i understand that the number of particles is for the whole mesh, no matter the size of itself.

[image]

So here, the smaller mesh is 4 times smaller than the other one, so the particles will be 4 times more dense from the smaller mesh compared to the big one.

What im looking to do is something like this :

[image]

so all faces will have to same particule density.

Comment: select you objects (the one with the correct particle system last) and press Ctrl+L and choose Modifiers

Comment: nope, that's not what im looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by using some settings in the particle system itself(If better result, please share it with me).

[image]

I assigned the same particle system to both planes here, small one got 1 face and big one got 4 faces as big as the small plane.

I cranked up the Hair number to 50k but assigned only 500 per face. So both planes got the same hair density.